# Javascript JSON Parsing Bug

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json, parsing

I am getting a very strange bug when I try to parse a string representation of a JSON array.

Here is the string:

```
[{"name":"param1","type":"text","label":"Param1","value":"Wowzers"},{"name":"param2","type":"text","label":"Param2","value":"Awesomesauce"}]
```

There doesn't seem to be an error or bad formating with the JSON, but for some reason when I call JSON.parse() on that String. Both of the 'value' properties are set to "undefined".

The weirdest part about all of this is that in another instance, the JSON parse works fine. Here is the string for the other instance.

```
[{"name":"start","type":"date","label":"Start Date","value":"2016-02-11T05:00:00.000Z","format":"EEEE, MMMM dd yyyy, h:mm a"},{"name":"finish","type":"date","label":"End Date","value":"2016-02-13T05:00:00.000Z","format":"EEEE, MMMM dd yyyy, h:mm a"}]
```

With this code, I can access the values and the returned array of objects have  value properties that are equated to the correct value. So it is parsing correctly.

So, for the first string, value comes back as undefined, but when I try to access the value using the code below, it works. I can log the values even though they don't technically exist in the array.

```
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.templateParams.length; i++) {
        var msg = $scope.templateParams[i];
        $log.info(msg);
        $log.info(msg.value);
    }
```

This gives:

```
Object { name: "param1", type: "text", label: "Param1", value: "Wowzers" }
Wowzers 
Object { name: "param2", type: "text", label: "Param2", value: "Awesomesauce" } 
Awesomesauce
```

I am really at a loss with this one, and have tried multiple work arounds, but can't figure anything out. Would appreciate any help.

UPDATE:

[Here is the console output. On the right I have one of the objects from the parsed array selected. As you can see the value is undefined, but for some reason I can still access in some parts of my code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnHM6.png)

Comment: What engine are you running this in? A quick test in Node 0.10 left both value params intact. Same in Chrome.

Comment: Where are you seeing them as `undefined`?  How are you trying to access them that you are getting `undefined`?  If your `$log.info(msg.value);` prints out the correct values, then that means the JSON and `JSON.parse()` are fine.

Comment: So what is the problem...? Maybe provide us full code that reproduces issue.

Comment: You need a complete example that reproduces your problem. You've said that `for some reason when I call JSON.parse() on that string, both of the 'value' properties are set to "undefined".` -- we can't reproduce that behavior by passing the given string into `JSON.parse`, so you haven't fully described the problem. Also, if you can log the values and they show up, in what way *have* you observed that they're set to `undefined`?

Comment: I'm not getting an error in the FF console.

Comment: It is a really tough situation to describe because it literally makes no sense. I attached an image of the console output to try and give you an idea what is going on. I don't fully understand it either because my other JSON parses are working. It is on this instance.

Comment: Probably something set the `value` attribute to `undefined` after you logged it as having the correct value. You need to post more of your code, show where you reference `value` in the html template and what else you might be doing.

Comment: @BradHoffman It looks to me like something's simply altering the value of `value` after you logged it.

Comment: try renaming the attribute `type` with something else.

Comment: It might say `undefined` in the inspector, but are you having trouble using the `value` in your code?  Where do you pass this object?  Maybe @apsillers is right and something is just updating the value?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. For my project, there are two types of fields that can be displayed depending on the 'type' of each parameter, and they are both tied to the same ng-model.

Even though the parsing would work, the 'value' property would be set to undefined by the other input field.

Thank you all for your help, and sorry I wasn't as descriptive as I could be. I didn't fully understand what was going on and how to explain it.